# Fetch data using LINQ query with left join and AsExpandable()

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have following two tables: Images and Articles

Both the tables are linked by the ImageId column.

An image can be associated with multiple articles.

For example: Images table has 100 rows and Articles table has 200 rows.

Out of these 100 images assume that only 90 are used across the Articles. In this case some of the images are repeated across many articles.

Here I want to fetch the unused 10 images (from Images table) and also want to include the ones that are associated with articles not more than 2 times. I want to ignore those images which are associated with the articles more than 2 times.

I tried the below linq query but it is not working for me.

```
 var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Image>();
                if (type != null && type != 0)
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(c => c.ImageType == type);
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keyword))
                {
                    predicate = predicate.And(c => c.Name.Contains(keyword) || c.Keyword.Contains(keyword));
                }

                int skip = numberofImages * (page - 1);

var images = (from imgs in context.Images
                              join art in context.Articles on imgs.ImageId equals art.ImageId into unusedImages
                              from img in unusedImages.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              group img by imgs.ImageId into grouped                              
                                   .AsExpandable()
                                   .Where(predicate)
                              orderby Guid.NewGuid(), imgs.ImageId descending
                              select imgs)
                                   .Skip(skip).Take(numberofImages).ToList();
```

[image]

Can any one help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Your code looks like it should fail - what does the `.AsExpandable()` belong to? That code definitely won't compile. What is the definition of `predicate`?

Comment: I have updated the code now. AsExpandable() is part of LinqKit (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: I know what it is - it can't be used after `grouped`.

Comment: You also can't do `orderby` `imgs` after `group`

Comment: Any other workaround or alternative solution to fix this issue is much appreciated

Comment: Can you make your code compile?

Answer (score 0):

split your query something like this,i wont complicate what is preferably simple

```
var usedArticles = (from item in  context.Articles
                    group item by imageid into newList
                    select new 
                      { 
                       imageid = newList.key,
                       count =newlist.count
                       }).ToList();  
var unwaantedImageIds = usedArticles.where(x=>x.count>2).Select(y=>y.imageId).ToArray();

   var unwantedImages =context.image.where(x=>unwaantedImageIds.contains(x.imageId));
    var result =  context.images.Except(unwaantedImageIds).ToList();
```